# how to find memory utilisation of a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I would like to find the memory utilised by a particular table in Oracle DB. Could anyone provide me the DB query for the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tables are stored on disk, not in memory; parts of a table may be present in the buffer cache but I'm not sure why (or how) you'd want to know that. Are you really asking about the amount of disk storage space the table is occupying? If not you'll need to explain what you do mean...

Answer (score 2):

Following what @Alex said,

You can check the table size on disk by querying `dba_segments`

```
select segment_name , segment_type , byte/1024/1024 mb 
from   dba_segments 
where  owner = 'X' 
and    segment_name= 'Y';
```

If you want to see which or how many blocks from the table are currently stored in the cache you can query `v$cache`. read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1059.htm)